# Monotone convergence theorem Lebesgue Integral

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Currently I am reading Rick Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples. 
I am going through the exercises of ch 1.5 I have trouble with the following exercise (ex 1.5.5)

If $ g_n \uparrow g $ (pointwise) and $\int g_1^{-} \,d\mu< \infty $ then $\int g_n\, d\mu \uparrow \int g\, d\mu$

My plan is to prove that $ g_n^- \uparrow g^- $ and by monotone convergence 
$\int g_n^- d\mu \uparrow \int g^- d\mu$ the same could be done for $ g^+_n $ and since $g = g^+ - g^-$ the exercise is (maybe) done.

The part that confuses me is the $\int g_1^{-} < \infty $ part, which says that $ g_1^{-} $ is Lebesgue integrable. Here are my questions:

- Why is this needed in the exercise ?
- The monotone convergence theorem requires the functions to be greater then zero but not integrable, why is that ? 
  (not related to the exercise)
- Are functions that are greater then zero all integrable, since one step of the construction of the integral is the construction of the integral for functions greater then zero ?
  (not related to the exercise)

PS.

- notation is taken from the book :  $ g^{-} = max\{-g, 0\}$
- by "function greater then zero" I mean $ f(x) \geq 0 \space for\space all \space x $

Comment: Do you mean g1 is the first term of the sequence ???

Comment: I retyped the exercise from the book (one to one ) and no explanation is given there. I supposed that g1 is the first element of the sequence. What else could it mean ?

Comment: Ya probably it's the same thing, or may be it's a typo becoz a condition on only the first term doesn't really makes sense